# Node JS app crashing itself even after using forever JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, forever

I am just tired of seeing my server goes down every time off and on.. Whenever I wake up it is down. Every time I have to go to SSH and then run

```
forever restartall
```

to restart my node app :(

I looked into the log file of forever and it says this

```
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

I have absolutely no idea why is this happening.

I am even running a cron job after every 50 minutes to auto restart node js in case it went down itself

```
0,50 * * * * * forever restartall
```

My app is running on Ubuntu EC2 AWS. And I use the following command to start my node app using forever:

```
forever -m5000 -w start index.js
```

Also, here are some recent snap of syslog since this happened recently

```
Jun  1 12:50:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[25924]: (ubuntu) CMD (forever restartall)
Jun  1 12:50:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[25923]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun  1 13:00:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[25930]: (ubuntu) CMD (forever restartall)
Jun  1 13:00:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[25929]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun  1 13:05:50 ip-172-31-28-35 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.28.35 on eth0 to 172.31.16.1 port 67 (xid=0x58e67545)
Jun  1 13:05:50 ip-172-31-28-35 dhclient: DHCPACK of 172.31.28.35 from 172.31.16.1
Jun  1 13:05:50 ip-172-31-28-35 dhclient: bound to 172.31.28.35 -- renewal in 1415 seconds.
Jun  1 13:09:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[26000]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Jun  1 13:17:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[26016]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun  1 13:20:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[26023]: (ubuntu) CMD (/home/ubuntu/cron/serv.sh)
Jun  1 13:20:01 ip-172-31-28-35 CRON[26022]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun  1 13:29:25 ip-172-31-28-35 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.28.35 on eth0 to 172.31.16.1 port 67 (xid=0x58e67545)
Jun  1 13:29:25 ip-172-31-28-35 dhclient: DHCPACK of 172.31.28.35 from 172.31.16.1
Jun  1 13:29:25 ip-172-31-28-35 dhclient: bound to 172.31.28.35 -- renewal in 1560 seconds.
Jun  1 13:34:39 ip-172-31-28-35 crontab[26289]: (ubuntu) LIST (ubuntu)
```

Here is the snapshot of the `free-h` command on my terminal of Ubuntu:
[image]

and here is snapshot of `df -h` command:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this and diagnose why my app crashes itself?

**LATEST EDIT AND LOGS AFTER FOLLOWING SUGGESTIONS:**
Uninstalled MySQL.
Added SWAP.
I added the uncaught exception code
Now when I woke up today the server was again down and this is my forever log http://kl1p.com/AI01 and these r my free-h just after the crash and syslog screenshot https://snag.gy/WMzqL0.jpg
https://snag.gy/0wG8Dx.jpg

Can anyone please help what is causing the RAM to go fully used and why Node JS is causing errors, how to fix them?

Comment: What is the type of Ubuntu EC2 instance you are using ?

Comment: shouldn't you remove the watch flag to give a test ? can you run top or `free -m` to check the memory usage of your server

Comment: Can you paste the output of "free -h" command on you Ubuntu instance?

Comment: Are you logging Node's `uncaughtException`?

Comment: @error2007s I have just added the snapshot from my Ubuntu terminal in the question. I am not sure which instance I am using. How do I check that? I am on the basic free tier amazon EC2 and this is the website http://talkwithstranger.com

Comment: if you're on free tier you're running a t2.micro - lets see the output of memory usage but you might be low on memory

Comment: @Wainage How do I log the Node's uncaught exception ?
I think there might be some Node js memory leak problem but still I don't know how to find and diagnose it? I am a newbie.

Comment: Out of memory is the most common cause of frequent Sigkill in Node.js. I guess you need to increase your memory space.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes I think it is t2.micro. I don't know why my server would be low on memory? I have pasted the output of free-h in my question, does that helps?
if its the memory problem (RAM) then why it starts working again once I restart my node app manually?
How do I free space on my EC2 Ubuntu instance? Please help me, I will give best answer to whoever who can solve my problem. thanks

Comment: What is the traffic for you application like?

Comment: @error2007s Thank you so much for your quick response. But can you please help me how do I increase the memory space on my Ubuntu ? Are you talking about the memory RAM or the Storage hard-drive of EC2?

Comment: Memory RAM What is the traffic for your application?

Comment: @error2007s The traffic is around 50-70 active users everytime. So how do I release the RAM on my t2.micro ubuntu ?
What is eating up the memory ? Btw I have added snapshot of df -h as well in my question. Also the -w flag was just testing, the problem was there before it as well :(

Comment: Well you cannot release the RAM in AWS EC2 instance. Create a Image of your EC2 instance and launch that image with a different instance type with like t2.small instance with 2 GB of RAM but be aware you will go out of free tier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113540/discussion-between-faizan-and-error2007s).

Comment: before you go and upgrade (might be a solution) try to add swap (t2.micro does not have by default) on your instance `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024000 count=3096` then `sudo mkswap /swapfile` and `sudo swapon /swapfile`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri okay so I can do this withi the free tier, right? Okay let me do this and update you.

Comment: yes you can do that on free tier

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I followed your instructions and did. and first it said, 3.2 GB copied. 2nd it says, https://snag.gy/sGlo1u.jpg and ran the third command too. Any further tips ?? Now after i did this the free-h says https://snag.gy/hC6FWn.jpg what is the meaning of the SWAP space here?

Comment: you have swap now - if you run your free command you'll see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113541/discussion-between-faizan-and-frederic-henri).

Comment: @FrédéricHenri hey man, I just followed all the suggestions and today after I woke up server is down again, I added all the latest logs after this latest crash in my question, can you please have a look and tell me how can I fix these?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect memory issues. Brute forcing `forever` restarts (cron's etc) will only mask the real issue.

Add this to your code:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log("Uncaught Exception:", err);
  process.exit(1);  // This is VITAL. Don't swallow the err and try to continue.
});
```

This will allow you to begin the process of diagnosing what is causing your node server to fail.

Comment: thanks for the code example. Where should I put it in my index.js main app file? should I put it on the top or where? My app is using socket.io.

Comment: Yeah. `index.js` should be fine. It captures the process event so will fire from anywhere an uncaught exception is raised. It's dangerous (if you try to continue instead of dying) but very useful to catch unforeseen errors.

Comment: I just added your code and after some time i checked my forever log and saw this line: Uncaught Exception: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null]
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #3
Server running at http://localhost:1337/

So is that the problem right? Now how do I fix where is this close line? the site is http://www.talkwithstranger.com/

Comment: That's `forever` getting the `process.exit(1)` from your code. Check your syslogs for the message that was `console.log`'d. You can grep it with `Uncaught exception` (or whatever you included in your log)

Comment: just checked my syslog and there is nothing in the log related to this 'close' error. You can see my syslog latest output when this exception was raised. here  https://snag.gy/uwkojX.jpg
and this is the snapshot of my forever log, https://snag.gy/fNqKl4.jpg i think there is one JS error on TCP. Not sure why these two errors r causing this. Btw I will mark ur answer as best as u helped me alot so far :) :)

Comment: Till I rectify this problem, how can I set the forever restart attempts to an infinite long number so the server don't goes down. I am trying to find what is causing this problem meanwhile. Also not sure what u meant by GREP over there, can you plz write the command that i have to run in terminal ?

Comment: Glad I could help. That log file may not be where node is logging to (this will depend on your server setup) but there will be (unless it's being sent to /dev/null) a log item with `uncaught exception` and the problem causing it somewhere.

Comment: As for `grep`; It's a command line tool to search for strings. Big topic. Google will cover it better than I ever could. You're going to love it.

Comment: Well node is logging its output in forever log file which I showed u and the other log file i am aware of is syslog file. I dont know where else to find that.

Comment: Can you please give me your email address? I added the uncaught exception code and now when I woke up today the server was again down and this is my forever log http://kl1p.com/AI01 and these r my free-h just after the crash and syslog screenshot https://snag.gy/WMzqL0.jpg
https://snag.gy/0wG8Dx.jpg I have added these latest in my question too.
Can you please help?

Comment: 1) Change `console.log` in the uncaught exception handler to `console.dir`. This way you'll see where the close error happened. 2) In case you still have the memory leak issue from the comment in your other question, check the link I posted there: https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications